# Where does the following property in requestScope? "requestScope.shouldRender"

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am begging to use primefaces and in this code for remoteCommand, I see #{requestScope.shouldRender} and I am puzzled

```
<h:form id="form">  

<p:commandButton value="Load" type="button" onclick="lazyload()" id="btnLoad" />  

<p:outputPanel id="lazypanel" layout="block">  
    <h:outputText value="This part of page is lazily loaded on demand using a RemoteCommand"   
            rendered="#{requestScope.shouldRender}"/>  
</p:outputPanel>  

<p:remoteCommand name="lazyload" update="lazypanel">  
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}"   
        target="#{requestScope.shouldRender}" />  
</p:remoteCommand>
```

I have seen primefaces class related with **commandButton** and **remoteCommand** but I dont find nothing related with **shouldRender**. I have search info about requestScope but I didnt find info.

How is possible to call "shouldRender"? Are there more properties/methods for to call the same way???

Kinds regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#{requestScope}` refers the request attribute map as you can obtain by [`ExternalContext#getRequestMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap%28%29) (which in turn delegates further to [`HttpServletRequest#get/setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), if you know the basic Servlet API).

The following line,

```html
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}"   
    target="#{requestScope.shouldRender}" />
```

basically sets a request attribute with the name "shouldRender" and a value of "true" in the current request when the parent command component is been invoked.

The rendered attribute of the output text is just intercepting on that during the render response of the very same HTTP request:

```
rendered="#{requestScope.shouldRender}"
```

All with all, it's just a way of setting an attribute in the request scope without the need for a whole request scoped backing bean. It does effectively the same as

```html
<p:outputPanel id="lazypanel" layout="block">  
    <h:outputText value="This part of page is lazily loaded on demand using a RemoteCommand"   
            rendered="#{bean.shouldRender}"/>  
</p:outputPanel>  

<p:remoteCommand name="lazyload" update="lazypanel">  
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}"   
        target="#{bean.shouldRender}" />  
</p:remoteCommand>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private boolean shouldRender;

    // Getter+setter.
}
```

Comment: Ah¡¡ **setPropertyActionListener** introduce properties through a actionListener. I had read wrong the documentation about _setPropertyActionListener_.  Thank you very much¡